# How do I preview a unix document file?

Tags: documentation

I want to preview these unix docs : https://github.com/axboe/liburing/tree/master/man , what should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by *preview*? Can't you simply *view* them with `man -l thefile.3`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas oh it works. I didn't know `man -l`. Thanks